# Which centaur is more 'official'?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, unearthed-arcana, centaur

I've got a player in my campaign and she's an equestrian, so naturally she likes centaur characters! She wished to use the centaur character race from Unearthed Arcana (UA), but I realize that there is a similar race described in Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica (GGR) which has subtle differences (like damage dealt by the hooves and charge distance).

I only wish to use the one that's officially supported by Wizards of the Coast, so which one should I use - UA or GGR? If both are officially supported, which is more popular?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is answered directly by the box text at the beginning of every single Unearthed Arcana article:

> **This Is Playtest Content**
>
> The material here is presented for playtesting and to spark your imagination. These game mechanics are in draft form, usable in your campaign but not refined by
>   final game design and editing. They aren’t officially part of the game and aren’t permitted in D&D Adventurers League events.
>
> If we decide to make this material official, it will be refined based on your feedback, and then it will appear
>   in a D&D book.

Anything in Unearthed Arcana is pre-release playtest content that might be finalized later in an actual book, adjusted and rebalanced based on the playtesting and feedback that came from UA. Only the book version is "official". So if both exist, the printed version is the "real" version that you should use.

In this case, the centaur and minotaur in the [Centaurs and Minotaurs UA](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Centaur.pdf) were playtest versions of the two races before they were actually published in GGtR.

Comment: The key sentence is in the last sentence "If we decide to make this material **official**, ..." which means this (UA) material is not official, yet.

Comment: Just to note, the Centaur featured in the Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica is the refined and printed version of the Unearthed Arcana one. It's the official one. It may or may not be AL legal, that I don't know, but that's more politics than anything.

Comment: @soxroxr GGtR is not AL legal at all (at present). If the AL Admins decide to create a Ravnica or MTG AL setting like they have for Eberron, it would likely be legal but only in the context of that AL setting.